# How can I respond in XML using ExpressJS?

Tags: node.js, express, node-mysql

I have a simple code that gives a JSON response for a specific route. Here's my current code:

```
var express = require('express')
  , async = require('async')
  , http = require('http')
  , mysql = require('mysql');

var app = express();

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: '****',
    password: "****",
    database: 'restaurants'
});

connection.connect();

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 1235);
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/images'));


app.get('/DescriptionSortedRating/',function(request,response){
    var name_of_restaurants;

    async.series( [
        // Get the first table contents
        function ( callback ) {
            connection.query('SELECT * FROM restaurants ORDER BY restaurantRATING', function(err, rows, fields)
                {
                        console.log('Connection result error '+err);
                        name_of_restaurants = rows;
                        callback();
                });

 }
   // Send the response
], function ( error, results ) {
    response.json({
        'restaurants' : name_of_restaurants
    });
} );

} );



http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

How can I make an XML response equivalent to the JSON above?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can use any number of the XML libraries available on npm.  Here's an example using the simply-named "[xml](https://npmjs.org/package/xml)" library:

```
var xml = require('xml');

response.set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
response.send(xml(name_of_restaurants));
```

See the module's documentation for a description of how it converts JavaScript objects to XML.  If you need things returned in a specific XML format, you'll have more work to do, of course.

Comment: Thanks i got the xml response from your answer .... but please have a look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/q/21399572/1083093 .... instead of two only one column is generating

Comment: response.set('Content-Type', 'application/xml') - i've read this is more correct, just throwing it out there

Comment: If you use 'application/xml' you need to specify the charset somewhere

Comment: TypeError: res.set is not a function

Comment: @Prageethgodage are you doing this from within a request handler?  if not, `res` won't be what you think it is.  https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.set

Comment: if i could like this a hundred times I would. after spending 3+ hours your answer is the first one I found that actually worked.

Comment: Thanks, @GregHarner, I'm glad it was helpful!

Answer (score 30):

As an update to this, it looks like res.type should be used instead as res.set does not give the same results.

```
res.type('application/xml');
```

More information can be found [in the API reference](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.set).

Comment: this answer helped, however `res.header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');` make more sense to me specially when you have lots of other headers