# npm run test should give XML test results

Tags: xml, jestjs

Currently we are running `npm run test` which is giving us output in text format. We need it in XML format so that we can provide it to TeamCity. Is there any command or any other way to do so?
Those are Jest tests.

Comment: Either the server needs to return response in xml format or the test needs to convert response to xml.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21398279/how-can-i-respond-in-xml-using-expressjs

Comment: Did you try looking for an appropriate reporter?